# Installing dotnet / "dotnet" no such file or command

Tags: raspbian

Getting smarter on the PI, but after installing dotnet on multiple computers, this is driving me nuts... see image - the file "dotnet" is there, the path is also good, but no joy.

Any hint would be appreciated.  (Yes I did ensure it was chmod +x rights)

[image]

Comment: is `/home/GFSAdmin0001/.dotnet` in your `PATH`? ... oh, wait, just reread that image

Comment: I never understood why this occurred - but I've moved on, rebuild the image, and moved on!